# Shifting more than 8 bits - leading to wrong output

Tags: c++, hex

I am trying to perform this operation, and im getting the wrong output.

```
signed char temp3[3] = {0x0D, 0xFF, 0xC0};
double temp = ((temp3[0] & 0x03) << 10) | (temp3[1]) | ((temp3[2] & 0xC0) >> 6)
```

I am trying to form a 12 bit number. get the last 2 bits of 0x0D, all 8 of 0xFF and first 2 of 0xC0 to form the binary number (011111111111) = 2047, however I am getting -1. When I break the first mask and shift of 10, I get 0. I dont know if this is my problem, trying to shift an 8 bit character 10 bits.

Comment: You're shifting an `int` left ten bits. Check each subexpression to make sure each is what you expect. Note that `0xFF` for a `signed char` is probably `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

When bit twiddling, *always use unsigned numbers*.

Change the array to `unsigned char`.

Add the 'U' suffix to each constant, because each constant is a *signed* integer by default.

BTW, right shifting is <s>undefined</s> *implementation defined* for signed integers.

Per comments, changed "undefined" to "implementation defined".

Comment: How do you mean, "right shifting is undefined for signed integers"?

Comment: It might be different for other versions, but in C++11, the value is *implementation-defined* if the left operand is signed and has a negative value. A positive value will work fine.

Comment: *Implementation defined* is not nearly the same as *undefined*.

Comment: I am performing this operation on several characters, and the resulting number could be positive or negative, thats why I used signed. Any advice?

Comment: Use unsigned.  Most character values (mappings) are unsigned.  Unsigned lets you use all the bits without any interpretations.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to address.

First up, c++ doesn't have 12 bit numbers. The best you can have are 16 bit. The top bit represents sign in twos complement form.

You also need to be very careful shift of the type of the number you are shifting. In your example, you are left shifting a char by over 8 bits. As a char is only 8 bits, you are zeroing it.

The following example gives a correct implmentation (for signed 12 bit numbers). There are no doubt more efficient ones.

```
// shift in top 2 bits
signed short test   =  static_cast<signed short>(temp3[0] & 0x03) << 10 ;

// shift in middle 8 bits
test   |=  (static_cast<signed short>(temp3[1]) << 2)  & 0x03FC;
// rightshift, mask and append lower 2 bits
test   |=  (static_cast<signed short>(temp3[2]) >> 6)  & 0x0003;
// sign extend top bits from 12 bits to 16 bits
test |= (temp3[0] & 0x02) == 0 ? 0x0000 : 0xF0000;
```

Comment: what does the last line do, specifficaly the ? and :

Comment: i'ts a ternary operator. Its just a shorthand way of writing an if statement. test is or'd with 0x0000 if the condition (temp3[0] & 0x02) == 0 is true, else test is or'd with 0xf000